# Unreal Engine Ray Cast is not in player y (pitch) rotation

Tags: unreal-engine4

Start and End position of the ray cast

[image: 1]

I need a way to make the end position of the ray cast rotate like the players y (pitch) rotation.

Comment: It's because you're using the player mesh, it doesn't rotate with the camera. Try using APlayerController->PlayerCameraManager->GetCameraRotation

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that i dont use a camera in my first person character and i dont find a way to implement it. I hope that you can help me.